# Convert a string with numbers represented in alphabets to numbers in a String

Tags: java, string, algorithm, hashmap

//We need to convert xyzoneyctwothreefourvone to numbers : 1,234,1

public static void cal(String s){

```
    HashMap<String, String> map= new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("zero", "0");
    map.put("one", "1");
    map.put("two", "2");
    map.put("three", "3");
    map.put("four", "4");
    s = "xyzoneyctwothreefourvone";
    int temp;
    StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
    ArrayList<StringBuilder> list = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
    StringBuilder strB1 = new StringBuilder();
    boolean isNum = false;

    for (int i = 0; i <= s.length() - 1; i++) {
        strB.append(s.charAt(i));
        if (strB.length() >= 3 && map.containsKey(strB.toString())) {
                isNum = true;
                strB1.append(map.get(strB.toString().toLowerCase()));
                strB = new StringBuilder();
            } else if (strB.length() > 5) {
                isNum = false;
                strB1.append("+");
                strB = new StringBuilder();
                i = i - 5;
            }
        }       

    System.out.println(strB1.toString());
```

}

Expected Output : +++1++234+1;
Current Output: +++1++234

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, it's missing a return

Answer (score 3):

It's because your else statement is executed whenever `(strB.length() > 5)` condition is fullfilled. But at the end, your `strB` contains string `vone` and so it doesn't have enough characters to execute this `else` statement.

However, you can achieve this with this code as well. It keeps things simple:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    s = s.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

s = s.replaceAll("[a-z]", "+");
```

Output

```
+++1++234+1
```

See the DEMO: https://ideone.com/Mjo9D5

Comment: Thank you Raman for the great solution! However since this was my interview question, we arent supposed to use "replaceAl". Can we have a solution without ReplaceAll ?